# Can I use 3.5mm jack microphone in clamshell mode?

Tags: mac, audio, microphone

I have read that new macbook pro models physically disconnect the Microphone when Macbook is in clamshell mode.

Does that mean that I won't be able to connect 3.5mm microphone as well in clamshell mode and use it?

Something like this:
https://www.amazon.in/Maono-AU-400-Lavalier-Microphone-Black/dp/B07JF9B592/ref=sr_1_3?dchild=1&keywords=3.5mm+microphone&qid=1594124148&s=electronics&sr=1-3

Comment: Where have you "read" this?

Comment: Here https://www.businessinsider.com/apple-macbook-air-and-2018-macbook-pro-disconnect-microphone-when-lid-is-closed-2018-11